# Using cellindex() to locate a cell that may move

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm just getting started learning JavaScript, and I am having some trouble inserting cells into a table.  I have a 1-row table of 3 cells and I want to insert a new cell to the left of whichever cell is clicked, but only after when I click on the "Insert" button.

Here is the HTML for the table:

```
<table border="1" id="table1">
    <tr id="row1">
        <td id="c1" onclick="c1()">Cell 1</td>
        <td id="c2" onclick="c2()">Cell 2</td>
        <td id="c3" onclick="c3()">Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button onclick="insert()">Insert</button>
```

If I manually designate the cell index like I did with Cell 2, it works fine, but if I try to detect the cell's index like I'm doing with Cell 3, it just inserts the new cell at index 0.

JavaScript:

```
var cell1=false,
    cell2=false,
    cell3=false,
    x;


function c1() {
    cell1=true;
}
function c2() {
    cell2=true;
}
function c3() {
    cell3=true;
    x=getElementById("c3").cellIndex;
}
function insert() {
    if (cell1==true) {
        // Not used yet
    }
    if (cell2==true) {
        document.getElementById("table1").rows[0].insertCell(1).innerHTML="New1";
    }
    if (cell3==true) {
        document.getElementById("table1").rows[0].insertCell(x).innerHTML="New3";
    }
    cell1=false;
    cell2=false;
    cell3=false;
};
```

I've tried a few variants both in the `c3()` function and in the `insert()` function, but each time it either didn't insert at all, or it inserts at index 0.

By the way, I'm trying to do this with pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your Javascript console for errors, it reports:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined

Change `getElementById` in `c3()` to `document.getElementById` to fix this.